# how to start mongod with node.js under windows10 OS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, windows-10

I'm work on my demo project. my mongoDB server run on local host.

Is there any way to start mongodb service (if its not running) when my up start to run?

Comment: Typescript is pretty irrelevant here. I suppose [tag:node.js] is more relevant…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[child_process.exec()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) is what you need.